# Execute ansible include_tasks until a certain condition is met (kind of while until loop)

Tags: ansible, until-loop

I want to execute an include tasks list until a certain condition is met, I do not have a fixed loop but execution depends upon a condition.

A sample play below

Tasks list playbook
`tasks.yml`

```
---

- name: "inc test-var {{ test_var }}"
  set_fact:
    test_var: "{{ test_var | int + 1  }} "
```

parent playbook `parent.yml`

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        test_var: '1'
        req_var: '4'

    - name: "Test multi run of task"
      include_tasks: ./includes/tasks.yml
      register: versions_result
      until: test_var is version(req_var, '<')
      retries: 5
```

here I am expecting `parent.yml` tasks to run multiple times but it only run once.
Could some one point out what I am doing wrong and how to run a task multiple times until a condition is met.

Cheers,

Comment: For the record why this is not working, `include_tasks` can't be used together with `until`: `ERROR! 'until' is not a valid attribute for a TaskInclude`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to `include_tasks` multiple times is to loop over the range of numbers till it reaches the required number. However as you expect the "parent" playbook will not be run multiple times, the tasks file will be.

**Consider the below example:**

Through my main playbook `parent.yml`, I would like to run `tasks1.yml` multiple times (as defined in `set_fact`).

```yml
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      num: 1
      req_num: 4
  - include_tasks: tasks1.yml
    loop: "{{ range(num, req_num + 1)|list }}"
```

And in my `tasks1.yml`, I have a simple `debug` message:

```yml
- debug:
    msg: "Run {{ item }}"
```

Includes `tasks1.yml` 4 times and gives below output when I run `ansible-playbook parent.yml`:

```sh
TASK [include_tasks] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /home/user/tasks1.yml for localhost
included: /home/user/tasks1.yml for localhost
included: /home/user/tasks1.yml for localhost
included: /home/user/tasks1.yml for localhost

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Run 1

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Run 2

# ...goes till "Run 4"
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I can not pull the increment logic out in the `parent.yml`.

Comment: used this as the reference and make my thing work, thanks.

Comment: In my case, the child `tasks1.yml` contain series of tasks to be run together in a conditional loop which only can be use with `until` at `parent.yml`. Imagine waiting for a logs to have some text, read, parse, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65916096/186334 https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/46203#issuecomment-556013701 I found this useful.