# ansible loop include_tasks and until success

Tags: loops, ansible, until-loop

I would like to know how to loop over multiple tasks until condition is met.

#main.yml

```
  - set_fact:
      num: 1
      req_num: 10

  - name:  Start to unregister entities
    include_tasks: output.yml
    loop: "{{ range(num, req_num + 1)|list }}"
```

#output.yml

```
  - name: get status
    raw: cat /tmp/output
    register: rawoutput

  - name: copy to localhost
    copy:
      content: "{{rawoutput.stdout}}"
      dest: /tmp/output1
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: reg output2
    shell: awk something /tmp/output1 |awk '/something/,0' |head -n something |tail -n something > /tmp/output2 ; cat /tmp/output2
    register: output2
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: compare output2
    debug:
      msg: "{{item}}"
    with_items: "{{ output2.stdout_lines }}"
    until: item == "Synced"
    retries: 2
    delay: 2
```

#cat /tmp/output2

```
Synced
Syncing
Synced
Failed
```

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164654/execute-ansible-include-tasks-until-a-certain-condition-is-met-kind-of-while-un), but the playbook quits when the subtask fail.

My goal is to make sure all the content from output2 is "Synced", loop `output.yml` until the result is "Synced", or failed after x attempts.

Appreciate if there is better way of doing this. thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think I found my answer [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/46203#issuecomment-556013701).

from ovski4

```
- name: 'Wait until success'
  block:
    - name: Set the retry count
      set_fact:
        retry_count: "{{ 0 if retry_count is undefined else retry_count|int + 1 }}"

    - name: Get server updated ip
      uri:
        url: https://localhost/ip
        return_content: yes
        status_code: 200
      register: ip

    - name: ssh to the server
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ ip }}"
        port: 22
        timeout: 30
        state: started
  rescue:
    - fail:
        msg: Ended after 5 retries
      when: retry_count|int == 5

    - debug:
        msg: "Failed to connect - Retrying..."

    - include_tasks: wait_until_success.yml
```